# kannel smsbox configuration display error log about keyword

Tags: kannel

I have a problem when running

```
bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf &
smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf &
```

Nothing wrong with bearerbox, but when it comes to execute the sms box it displays the error below. My purpose is to send an sms from my modem.
Any idea how to fix this? Thank you

```
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] INFO: Service global sender set as ''
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13013.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 4245.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) maps to pid 4245.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Including port 13013, fd 8 for polling in server thread
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread)
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] INFO: Set up send sms service at port 13013
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread)
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread) maps to pid 4245.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: ----------------------------------------------
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: Kannel smsbox version 1.4.4 starting
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] ERROR: Group 'sms-service' may inlcude either 'keyword' or 'keyword-regex'.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] ERROR: Couldn't create a URLTranslation.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: urltrans_add_cfg failed
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(gw_backtrace+0xe0) [0x55b797599e50]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(gw_panic+0x167) [0x55b797599fc7]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(main+0x1576) [0x55b7975736f6]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f2d57ad8b97]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(_start+0x2a) [0x55b797573a8a]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] INFO: Service global sender set as ''
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 4245.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) maps to pid 4245.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Including port 13013, fd 8 for polling in server thread
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread)
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] INFO: Set up send sms service at port 13013
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread)
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread) maps to pid 4245.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: ----------------------------------------------
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] DEBUG: Kannel smsbox version 1.4.4 starting
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] ERROR: Group 'sms-service' may inlcude either 'keyword' or 'keyword-regex'.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] ERROR: Couldn't create a URLTranslation.
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: urltrans_add_cfg failed
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(gw_backtrace+0xe0) [0x55b797599e50]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(gw_panic+0x167) [0x55b797599fc7]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(main+0x1576) [0x55b7975736f6]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f2d57ad8b97]
2018-10-19 09:40:13 [4245] [0] PANIC: smsbox(_start+0x2a) [0x55b797573a8a]
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that is causing this error.

Comment: i only execute smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf & to open the smsbox

Comment: hi, I've edited your question so that it's easier to read and understand. Please note that it's always better to put the main question *before* the logs/long error traces etc; you should also format your code as code: as you can see, without that Matt didn't even see the code at first glance. Finally, if you reply somebody in comments, use mentions (@username) so that they see your reply

Comment: hi thank you man @YakovL. im in rush in writing this question sorry about it

Comment: i only execute smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf & to open the smsbox @MattD